# how to get required cell data in excel file using OleDb in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, excel-2007, excel-2003

actually i am trying to convert excel file data to xml file. my requirement is i need to get required cell data from excel and i can edit the xml tags according to my requirement. is it possible?????

and is it write way to use  OleDb for this????

this is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            System.Data.DataSet ds;
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

            MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\\Desktop\\xl2xml\\test_2003.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

            MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
            //MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Product");

            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Myrequireddata from required cell");  

            ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(ds);
            MyConnection.Close();
            ds.WriteXml(@"C:\Desktop\xl2xml\Product.xml");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. I have done the same thing before. Your concept is correct. Here I used Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library to read excel file.

However you can read the excel file into a Dataset and then you can go through the Dataset object to find required data.

Comment: thanks for reply....actually that excel file have normal data like:(SuperMarketName|product|imported|sales|price|Rs_in_words|total).actually i need XML file in format like:<SuperMarketA1 product ="product_name" imported ="how much imported" sales ="how many saled" price ="price" Rs_in_words ="Rupees">   <total money="total money" /> </SuperMarketA1>   <SuperMarketA2 product ="product_name" imported ="how much imported" sales ="how many saled" price ="price" Rs_in_words ="Rupees">   <total money="total money" /> </SuperMarketA2>

Comment: i am not getting how to reply to ur message,so add comment like this. sorry fr not aligned properly. i knw its inconvenience for reading. please help me...........i am new to this community as well as new to c#. thanks in advance...............